# tippocanoe feature filter not working

Tags: geojson, vector-tiles, mbtiles, mapbox-gl

I use [tippocanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) to build [Mapbox Vector Tiles](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/vector-tiles/) from GEOJSON features but can't get the filter to work.

I use a geojson file which contains millions of features and want to filter them for different zoom levels using property "ZOOM".

My geojson file looks like that:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "OBJECTID": "2580023",
        "ZOOM": 2
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -95.847916666999936,
              41.16875
            ],
            ...
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I try to use this tippocanoe command but resulting vector tiles contain all the features and not just the once where "ZOOM"<3:

```
tippecanoe --no-tile-size-limit --feature-filter='{"features": ["<", "ZOOM", 3]}' -Z3 -z3 -o output.mbtiles input.geojson
```

Something is wrong in the *--filter-feature* attributes. Actually I suspect that "features" is not ok but I don't know what to put there. But the filter itself should be like that as described in [Mapbox GL Style Specification](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#types-filter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out that the first attribute in the filter has to be the layer name where it should get applied to.

If you don't define any layer name, the filename without the dot is used as layer name. So for example, if your file is called *input.geojson*, this command works:

```
tippecanoe --no-tile-size-limit --feature-filter='{"inputgeojson": ["<", "ZOOM", 3]}' -Z3 -z3 -o output.mbtiles input.geojson
```